# How can I write data into a row in Virtual Studio? (MS Access Database file"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

I would like to make a small application what can make easier my work.

I have to make one ordering process some labels where I have a plan and from the plan I have to one excel list making with the labelnames what will be printed by the Manufacturer. We have a lot of type of the label (names) but they are fixing. (160 pieces differentnames).

So I make this always if I get a new plan then I make new label-list. I do it alway by hand cell by cell.. Sometime I have to filling out 400 cell for one plan... I don’t have a lot’s of time to this..
So I started making my first Windows app with Visual Studio(in Windows From – Visual Basic).

I found some cool video, so I already have the „basics”.

I connected one MS Access database to my Project where I would like to store the datas.

And now i have trouble.. I have some Comboboxes. I would like to choose some cases and then I would like to update the database where the rows will be filled with the correct values. If its done, i can this exporting to excel and sendig forward to the Manufacturer.

I have a textbox where I write the Plan name (it linked to the database first Column)

And then:

So the Combobox1 have Sektor A, B, C, D ,E, F (six value)

The Combobox2 have 09RRU, 09RSU, 18RRU ... empty - (eight value)

The Combobox3 have 21RRU, 21RSU, 26RRU ... empty - (eight value)

The Combobox4 have ja or nein (only two value)
and so on.. I have 8 Combobox.

My Idea:

If I select the Sektor A and 09RRU , the another two is empty and nein, then I click on the Update button I would like to get back in database 09.SekA1, 09.SekA2, AISG.SekA

If I select the Sektor A and 09RRU and 21RRU and ja, then after click Update, I would like get 09.SekA1, 09.SekA2, 21.SekA1, 21.SekA2, 09.21.SekA1, 09.21SekA2, AISG.09.21.SekA
….

I can every type of labels line by line writing if needed, I think I have to do this. I don’t think so can I dynamic Arrays making which can the different String e.g. ( Text (09) & Text (.SekA) & Text(1)) creating. I just now started the VB..

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox8.SelectedIndexChanged
    SektorForm1()
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged        
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox4_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox3.SelectedIndexChanged        
End Sub

Private Sub SektorForm1()
    BEschriftungenDataSet.Standort.RRU18Column = "18.SekA1"
    BEschriftungenDataSet.Standort.RRU21Column = "18.SekA2"
    BEschriftungenDataSet.Standort.RRU26Column = "AISG.18.SekA"
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.StandortTableAdapter.Fill(Me.BEschriftungenDataSet.Standort)
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 5
    ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = 3
    ComboBox3.SelectedIndex = 3
    ComboBox4.SelectedIndex = 1
    ComboBox5.SelectedIndex = 1
    ComboBox6.SelectedIndex = 1
    ComboBox7.SelectedIndex = 1
    ComboBox8.SelectedIndex = 0
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    On Error GoTo SaveErr
    StandortBindingSource.EndEdit()
    StandortTableAdapter.Update(BEschriftungenDataSet.Standort)
    MessageBox.Show("Saved")
End Sub
```

Could some one for me Helping what is wrong in my code? I tried some data inserting to tha database when I choose someting in Combobox1 but it doesn't work..

I get failures: BC30526 Property'RRU18Column' is 'ReadOnly' and BC30311 Value 'String' cannot be converted to 'DataColumn'..
And giving some help how I sould staring building up my cases to my Combobox chooses..

Thanks guys

Comment: `BC30526` is because you are trying to assign a value to that column/property, it's ReadOnly of course; `BEschriftungenDataSet.Standort.RRU18Column = "18.SekA1"`, that line. The other error is simply because you are trying to pass a string that takes a `DataColumn` type, not a string. Have you tried putting breakpoints in your code and stepping through?

Comment: But what I don't understand: Why can I add data from textfield with the same settings and why don't working in this case?
I tough the same but if I try just give "apple" or somethingelse without numbers also I get the Same Error.